# Multi dimensional arrays searching workbooks - google Spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets

I'm currently working with Google Spreadsheets and having couple of problems with text searches. 
In particular I have to overcome the 'range' limit with text functions like find, match etc. (I want to input matrixes as 'range' but they take just vectors). I've seen that many people do this on Excel scripting in VBA. is there any adaptation of something like this[vba find =find() script](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm) for spreadsheets?

The first section is the one which concerns me: finding text and selecting the cell (I have to pick the value 2 rows below the cell containing text).

Thanks beforehand guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Excel OFFSET function returns a reference to a range that is offset a number of rows and columns from another range or cell.
syntax:

```
OFFSET( range, rows, columns, [height], [width] )
```

where

1. range is the starting range from which the offset will be applied.
2. rows is the number of rows to apply as the offset to the range. This
   can be a positive or negative number.
3. columns is the number of columns to apply as the offset to the
   range. This can be a positive or negative number.
4. height is optional. It is the number of rows that you want the
   returned range to be. If this parameter is omitted, it is assumed to
   be the height of range.
5. width is optional. It is the number of columns that you want the
   returned range to be. If this parameter is omitted, it is assumed to
   be the width of range.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time. 
Secondly, since I have to search for a name in the entire spreadsheet, and that's the problem. the formula should look like this:
    =OFFSET('Hours Sheet'!$A$1:$T$100="Tim", 2, 0)
so I should use as range the find formula which searches the name of the employee, afterwards it offsets by 2 rows and give me the value that I want... 
still problems using multi-dimensional arrays as search ranges